# no me reconoce las clases en un div con v-for

Tags: vue.js, class

todo funcionaba bien hasta que tuve que usar el v-for, cuando pasaba los elementos con JS no habia problema, pero ahora me tira error [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
`

`
y el error me lo marca en esta linea:
const offset = -index * (carouselItems[0].clientWidth + 16); 
repito que antes no habia problemas y si saco el v-for deja de marcarlo

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 0):

Pareciera que carouselItems[0] es undefined, qué contiene la variable carouselItems? Quizás debas hacer v-for="item in carouselItems", luego item.clientWidth

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).